# Extract a part of a filename

Tags: filenames, string

I have the filename `TRNPRD.STD.BSRE.BREX.J.20190520.V02.PRET` on a Linux machine, from which I need to extract only `TRNPRD.STD.BSRE`.

I tried the following command:

```
echo TRNPRD.STD.BSRE.BREX.J.20190520.V02.PRET | awk -F'.' '{for(i=0;++i<=NF-5;) printf $i".";}'
```

But it returns the desired results with an extra dot at the end that I don't need:

```
TRNPRD.STD.BSRE.
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: There might not be any difference, but are you trying to get the first 3 fields, or remove the last 5?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using `cut` here, as `awk` is a little overkill for this task.

```
$ echo TRNPRD.STD.BSRE.BREX.J.20190520.V02.PRET | cut -d . -f -3
TRNPRD.STD.BSRE
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `awk` command is adding the `.` because you're telling it to print `$i` and then a `.`. So it ends with an extra `.`. You could instead do:

```
$ echo TRNPRD.STD.BSRE.BREX.J.20190520.V02.PRET | 
    awk -F'.' '{for(i=0;++i<=NF-6;) printf $i"."; print $(NF-5)}'
TRNPRD.STD.BSRE
```

Or, just print the first 3 directly:

```
$ echo TRNPRD.STD.BSRE.BREX.J.20190520.V02.PRET | 
    grep -oP '^([^.]+\.){2}[^.]+'
TRNPRD.STD.BSRE
```

Of course, you could also use your original approach and just delete the extra `.`:

```
$ echo TRNPRD.STD.BSRE.BREX.J.20190520.V02.PRET | 
    awk -F'.' '{for(i=0;++i<=NF- 5;) printf $i".";}' | sed 's/\.$//'
TRNPRD.STD.BSRE$
```

The best and simplest solution, however, will be `cut` [as suggested by @Panki](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/532261/22222).

Comment: It'd be better to avoid using printf on the fields directly. `printf "%s",$i"."`

Comment: @Dabombber true, but i) I wanted to use the same command as the OP to keep things simple and not confusing and ii) it doesn't make any difference in this case where the input is just static text. But yes, you're quite right, that is good practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the last five dot-delimited substrings from your string:

```
$ name=TRNPRD.STD.BSRE.BREX.J.20190520.V02.PRET
$ echo "${name%.*.*.*.*.*}"
TRNPRD.STD.BSRE
```

This applies [a standard parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) that removes the substring matching the given pattern from the end of the value of `$name`.

---

If you want to *keep* the three first dot-delimited substrings in your string:

```
$ name=TRNPRD.STD.BSRE.BREX.J.20190520.V02.PRET
$ echo "${name%.${name#*.*.*.}}"
TRNPRD.STD.BSRE
```

This first removes the first three bits from `$name` using `${name#*.*.*.}` (`#` removes from the left/start, `%` removes from the right/end), and then uses that result to remove the tail end of the string, leaving the three first dot-delimited bits.

---

The below suggestions would work as long as the value in `$name` does not contain newlines (which is an issue with any solution using standard text-processing tools).

Your `awk` code always prints a dot at the end of each field.  To make it slightly more robust, you could use something like

```
awk -v OFS="." '{ n=split($0,a,"\."); $0=""; for (i=1; i<=3 && i<=n; ++i) $i=a[i]; print }' <<<"$name"
```

This would split the value up on the dots, then create an output record of the first three parts of that value and print it (with the output field separator, `OFS`, set to a dot).

To make it discard the last five bits rather than keep the first three:

```
awk -v OFS="." '{ n=split($0,a,"\."); $0=""; for (i=1; i<=n-5; ++i) $i=a[i]; print }' <<<"$name"
```